# How can I form a pair of input (coming from two different location) before passing it to the map in mapreduce job

Tags: mapreduce

I am new to the Map reduce world.

I have inputs files in two different locations. I want to pass them to my mapper in pairs after doing the merge sort. How can I do this?

For eg.

```
/folder1/file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt  
/folder2/file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt
```

sample content of files:

```
folder1/file1.txt  
"Key1": "value1"  

folder2/file1.txt  
"Key1": "value2"
```

After Appling merge sort.

`"key1" : "value1,value2"` as input to my mapper.

Please help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need two map-reduce jobs in order to get this to work properly. The first job should combine the files together, so that it's input is in form `"key1" : "value1,value2"`. Then make a second job that does whatever you originally wanted to do, which uses the output of the first job as input.

Alternatively - if possibble -  move the processing you want to do from the mapper to the reducer, and simply pass both files into the job. The reducer will process the values the same regardless of which file they came from.

Comment: Actually, Input is very big around 24TB which makes it impossible for me to run the first job itself.  Also I used the same strategy as mentioned by u in the alternate section.  But no luck yet.

Comment: @RajeshPandey what processing are you doing that you cannot move that to the reducer? If you post that, I might be able to help rearrange your algorithm a bit, so that you can do the processing in the reducer, and so have the files combined automatically by the reducer. Might not be possible, but worth a look at least.